I am having issues accessing a an object in a bucket using S3 pre-signed URL. Can someone help on this?
I have a ECS fargate service which have a lambda role. I am granting that role permissions in to getObject, read and write objects in s3 bucket in the same AWS account. When I run the test from my virtual machine (which have access and doesn't need a role access), I am able to access the contents then using the pre-signed URL return from the test.
I am using bucket.grantReadAndWrite from CDK to grant the access to the role.
The thing is that when I try running it in an environment where the service would assume the role and try to run it, I am getting the exception Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: <presignedUrl>. Even when I try to access the URL from the browser (the one that I get in the exception), it states the same thing Access denied 403.

I tried checking the expiration time for the URL and it states 24 hours which is good.
I tried checking the permissions for the role and it does have read and write permissions including to getObject.


A pre-signed URL inherits the permissions associated with the credentials that were used to create the pre-signed URL. For example, if you use a permanent credential associated with an IAM User, then the pre-signed URL will be able to access the object if the IAM User is permitted to access the object. If, however, you create the pre-signed URL using temporary credentials associated with an IAM Role then the pre-signed URL will only be valid if those temporary credentials are still valid. This might be fine for short durations, but would likely not work an hour later.

Got it, but my tests tries to access it within 2 or 3 secs of it being created using the same IAM role and still get access denied. That should not be the case which is why I am kinda confused.

I have set the expiration for the URL to be one day, so that means it doesn't matter if the credentials expire prior to that?

If the credentials used to create the pre-signed URL expire, then the pre-signed URL also expires. Basically, you are 'signing' the URL to say "I approve access to this object as if it were me". So, if the entity giving that approval no longer has access rights, then the pre-signed URL also fails. You might want to confirm that the IAM Role has permission to access the S3 object, otherwise the pre-signed URL it creates won't have access either.
